# How to make dot match newline characters using regular expressions

Tags: php, regex

I have a string that contains normal characters, white charsets and newline characters between <div> and </div>.

This regular expression doesn't work: `/<div>(.*)<\/div>`. It is because `.*` doesn't match newline characters. How can I do this?

Comment: The word is "regular" and the answer is that it depends on the implementation you're using.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You need to use the [DOTALL](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) modifier (`/s`).

```
'/<div>(.*)<\/div>/s'
```

This might not give you exactly what you want because you are greedy matching. You might instead try a non-greedy match:

```
'/<div>(.*?)<\/div>/s'
```

You could also solve this by matching everything except '<' if there aren't other tags:

```
'/<div>([^<]*)<\/div>/'
```

Another observation is that you don't need to use `/` as your regular expression delimiters. Using another character means that you don't have to escape the `/` in `</div>`, improving readability. This applies to all the above regular expressions. Here's it would look if you use '#' instead of '/':

```
'#<div>([^<]*)</div>#'
```

However all these solutions can fail due to nested divs, extra whitespace, HTML comments and various other things. HTML is too complicated to parse with Regex, so you should consider using an HTML parser instead.

Comment: Can I ask you why there is [^<] in '/<div>[^<]*<\/div>/m'? I know what it means but I don't understand why you are using it. I think that it can cause problems for example with <div>some <b>bold</b> text</div>

Comment: +1 for the regex vs. HTML insight. If you need to work with HTML, you probably want some sort of DOM.

Comment: Ok, I know that it is subjective but I think that problems only with `<div>a<div>b</div>c</div>` are lesser evil than problems with all nested tags. Btw I think that you are missing `/m` in the last expression because it will be still only single-line.

Comment: `/s` is the modifier that lets the dot match newlines (single-line or DOTALL mode); `/m` changes the behavior of `^` and `$` (multiline mode).  Unless you're working with Ruby, where multiline mode is always on and `/m` turns on DOTALL mode.  Or JavaScript, which has no DOTALL mode.

Comment: @Mark, if you're using the negated character class `[^<]*`, which may be a good idea depending on the nature of the subject string, I'd make it possessive to prevent possible needless backtracking: `#<div>([^<]*+)</div>#`.

Comment: DOTALL modifier!? like WTF, who the h..ll ever came with this crap, it's ridiculous, stupid php

Answer (score 20):

To match all characters, you can use this trick:

```
%\<div\>([\s\S]*)\</div\>%
```

Comment: That's a hack to work around JavaScript's lack of a DOTALL/single-line mode; it isn't needed in PHP.  Also, `<` and `>` have no special meanings, so you don't have to escape them.

Comment: @Alan Moore It may be a hack, but it's a good trick to note in general, because you don't need to worry about mode support or which symbolic tokens to escape. Plus you may not want to change the mode for the whole regex.

Comment: @AlanMoore In case anyone stumbles on this, JavaScript does have an "s" flag (maybe it didn't in 2012) for RegExp to provide DOTALL behavior. https://javascript.info/regexp-introduction#flags

Comment: But this question is tagged with "PHP". Does it work in other than JavaScript? Does it actually work with newline characters in PHP? User *Hossein* has left the building, so others need to chime in.

Answer (score 17):

You can also use the `(?s)` [mode modifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html). For example,

```
(?s)/<div>(.*?)<\/div>
```

Answer (score 5):

There shouldn't be any problem with just doing:

```
(.|\n)
```

This matches either any character except newline **or** a newline, so every character. It solved it for me, at least.

Comment: Have you tried it in php? I guess you haven't, it produces: "Compilation failed: nothing to repeat at offset 1"

Comment: Where did you try it? Can you check it in PHP (the question is tagged with PHP)?

Answer (score 1):

An option would be:

```
'/<div>(\n*|.*)<\/div>/i'
```

Which would match *either* newline or the dot identifier matches.

Comment: What about `\r'? This may be the reality in a web context (e.g., PHP handling form data)?

Answer (score -1):

There is usually a flag in the regular expression compiler to tell it that dot should match newline characters.

Comment: The suspense! Can you reveal what the flag is? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/1985952/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).