# Using preg_match_all to get items from HTML

Tags: php, regex

I have a number of items in a table, formatted like this

```
<td class="product highlighted">
Item Name
</td>
```

and I am using the following PHP code

```
$regex_pattern = "/<td class=\"product highlighted\">(.*)<\/td>/";
preg_match_all($regex_pattern,$buffer,$matches);
print_r($matches);
```

I am not getting any output, yet I can see the items in the html.

Is there something wrong with my regexp?

Comment: I smell that something like that has been asked numerous times... . Please use the search.

Comment: E.g. [How to make dot match newline characters using regular expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1985941/how-to-make-dot-match-newline-characters-using-regular-expressions)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apart from your using regex to parse HTML, yes, there is something wrong: The dot doesn't match newlines.

So you need to use

```
$regex_pattern = "/<td class=\"product highlighted\">(.*?)<\/td>/s";
```

The `/s` modifier allows the dot to match any character, including newlines. Note the reluctant quantifier `.*?` to avoid matching more than one tag at once.

Comment: @user813813 For reference, see the documentation about the [dot in PHP regex syntax](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.dot.php), and [pattern modifiers](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php).

Answer (score 3):

In order to match your example, you will need to add the *dot all* flag, `s`, so the `.` will match newlines.

Try the following.

```
$regex_pattern = "/<td class=\"product highlighted\">(.*?)<\/td>/s";
```

Also note that I changed the capture to non-greedy, `(.*?)`. It's best to do so when matching open ended text.

It's worth noting regular expressions are not the right tool for HTML parsing, you should look into [DOMDocument](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php). However, for such a simple match you can get away with regular expressions provided your HTML is well-formed.