# Multiple matches in one array string

Tags: php, arrays, regex

I'm trying to match `^Description^*http://google.com*` and convert into URL. It's working with JS, but I don't know how implement this into PHP Array.
My JS looks like this:

```
var that = $(this);
    var vid = that.html().match(/\^(.*)\^/gm); 
    var vid2 = that.html().match(/\*(.*)\*/gm);
    var vid2 = jQuery.trim(vid2).slice(1,-1);
    var vid1 = jQuery.trim(vid).slice(1,-1);
     that.html(function(i, h) {
        return h.replace(/\^(.*)\^\*(.*)\*/gm, '<a target="_blank" href="'+vid2+'">'+vid1+'</a>');
    });
```

And my PHP Array:

```
$find = array('/\*\*([^*]+)\*\*/', '/@(\\w+)/');
$replace = array('<span style="font-weight:bold">$1</span>', '<a href=/profile/$1>@$1</a>');
$result = preg_replace($find, $replace, $comment_text);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done with that :)

```
$find = array('/\*\*([^*]+)\*\*/', '/@(\\w+)/', '/\^(.*)\^\*(.*)\*/');
$replace = array('<span style="font-weight:bold">$1</span>', '<a href=/profile/$1>@$1</a>','<a target="_blank" href="$2">$1</a>');
$result = preg_replace($find, $replace, $comment_text);
```

Answer (score 0):

To match the regular experession `^Description^*http://google.com*` in PHP you could use the /s modifier (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1985941/how-to-make-dot-match-newline-characters-using-regular-expressions)) instead of the ^ in the middle of the Regex. I tested the code [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/dee6fbf29e65d85558903cc7fa28cfb098e7a040).

```
<?php
$find = array('/^Description.*\*(.*)\*/s');
$replace = array('<a href="$1">$1</a>');
$comment_text = 'Description 
*http://google.de*';
$result = preg_replace($find, $replace, $comment_text);
echo $result;
```